# Select items runs fine in Chrome et al but not on Android G-1 browser?

Tags: javascript, android, browser, setfocus

This little web page runs fine on my desktop but when selecting the area with a G-1 Android device (select box that says statewide..) the data refreshed with the requested data in the table but the text in the select box does not change,,, the other select boxes (month and year) work fine.. Fwiw the data is still rough and so is the gadget...
I've rebooted and restarted the g-1 to no avail..
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4303088/gadgetdraftok.html

The broader question, i guess, here is how to debug a web page on any android browser? we don't have a firebug equivalent..

Further I confirmed the same bug in the Moto Cliq browser (also old still a 1.5) very strange every once in a while the G-1 operates correctly, but I can't figure out how to get it to do it, just that every once in a while the select shows in the window when selected and the data refreshes..

I have verified that this seems to be a verified bug in the early browsers... so now I'm trying to figure a work around, I added setFocus on the select box but it is ignored on the Android G-1
****New info****
I actually used this test tool from W3schools try-it site and it demonstrates the non-behavior in just a few lines..
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_focus i.e. it works fine on desktop but does not give focus when on phone.. anyone have a work around idea? ( I figured setFocus would be my silver bullet but sadly no)

I have three select boxes on the app so I need to display the selected info...as the selection is served.. not just initialization. FWIW the behavior seems to be on select boxes that have the selection dynamically loaded,, when I finish all three boxes will need dynamic loading now only the area box is dynamic, year/month are coded and so work.

Comment: Hmm. Works fine on my Nexus One running Android 2.2.

Comment: Works fine on my Droid Incredible as well, running 2.1 although the widget starts out really small.  I'd imagine its a bug in the older version of the web borwser

Comment: Thanks for the feedback glad to hear that it may be specific to the G-I wonder if I change the html type or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue, A) spelled areas right in set a focus routine called at end of data refresh, (at one point I had it as area vs. areas) this forces the select to update the value and I went ahead and used the value of the select in the table head to provide "back-up visual confirmation that the area is elected.. works fine now ! :-)
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4303088/gadgetdraftok3.html

So the main deal seems to be if you want to show the value, set the focus... I think, even though that is not required on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

What doesn't work properly are the items that contain spaces in them, e.g. *Lee County*.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out I was aware of it  (the spaces issue and plan to just "fix" those labels..,, but the issue I'm trying to get at is the ones that do work,, don't change the display in the select box where statewide is when a new area , like "Athens" is selected, yet the data is refreshed,, again this behavior is so far limited to the G-1 so perhaps I'm being a bit anal but since I have a G-1 I'd like to fix the d*** thing before moving on..